# How to send message without user interaction in kony

Tags: temenos-quantum

I need to send a message to the specific phone number without 'user interaction'.  Suppose there is button is called approved.  If approved button is clicked  then message should be sent without user interaction.

I have tried with the kony API "kony.phone.sendSMS("0123456789", "your leave approved")".  The message sent successfully but one page has opened with the send option in android mobile.

Is it possible to send message without 'send' option means direcltly?.  If possible please give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you need to write the code in native Android, integrate it as an FFI and then call this method in Kony.